smartd scheduled short test overloads system & crashes it
DEVICESCAN -a -o on -S on -s (S/../.././02|L/../01/02) -l selftest

Latest Debian storage server.
It happened already at least 3x. From time to time it also crashes the whole system. No idea why, SAS HBAs + expanders overloaded. PSU is 1700W, and whole system during the unusual test runs 550W.
I thought it may be the usual offender of bugged file indexing by plocate/mlocate/updatedb - there are no such services active on the server.
From time to time it seems to collide with another service, or I do not why. I can't figure out what may be the problem.
Server has 60+ drives, and two days ago it happened again. 2 am wild noise from server, all drives running flat out. UPS overloaded, system crashed.
In log before the crash is only scheduled short selftest.
Usually, smartctl short/long test runs in background. One, notices no wild increase in I/O activity.
Any suggestions, please?
